# updating database by getting user id and sending AJAX call

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, prepared-statement

I have a page that I accept or deny new users. When someone is accepted they go to a section called Accepted Users and in that section the admin have to change their permission level or group#. So in the following I am getting the user_id from the user_request table for that specific user and wanting to update my users table by the id. I am only wanting to update the 'group' by the option box through an AJAX call to my php file.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Nothing is being updated into my db. I get no errors in the console,

```
<?php
$con2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$run2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
$runUsers2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($run2);

    if( $numrows2 ) {
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run2)){
            if($row2['status'] == "Approved"){

                $approved_id        = $row2['user_id'];
                $approved_firstname = $row2['firstname'];
                $approved_lastname  = $row2['lastname'];
                $approved_username  = $row2['username'];

    if ($approved_firstname == true) {
        echo "Name - ". $approved_firstname . " " . $approved_lastname . "</br>" . 
                "Username - ". $approved_username . "</br></br>"
?>
<div class="change_group_button"> 
     <a class="change_group" href="javascript:void(0)">Change User Permission</a>
</div><br>
<div id="light" class="change_group_popup">
    <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>

    <form id="update_group" name="Group" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <div class="field">
        <label for="group">Group</label>
        <select value='<?php echo $approved_id; ?>' id='approved_id' name='group' required>
            <option value=''><?php echo htmlentities($group); ?></option>
            <option value="1">Bench</option>
            <option value="2">Spectator</option>
            <option value="3">Team Member</option>
            <option value="4">Commissioner</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

AJAX call. I am not sure if my data part is right..

```
//AJAX call for updating the group
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#update_group').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'user_group_update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: $(this).val(), //id
                update_group: $(this).val() //group level
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
                $("#success").fadeIn();
                $("#success").show();
                $('#success').html('User Permission Level Changed!');
                $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
            },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown )
            {
              // alert on an http error 
              alert( textStatus +  errorThrown );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

user_group_update file

```
$approved_id = $_POST['id'];
$change_group = $_POST['update_group'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET group=? WHERE id=?");
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User Group update prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $change_group, $approved_id);
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User Group update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
        die('User Group update execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems:

1) you are combining the group id and approved id into one select element. that's not how forms work. you need a separate field for approved id, something like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_id; ?>" id="approved_id" name="id" />
<select id='group_id' name='group' required>
    <option value=''><?php echo htmlentities($group); ?></option>
    <option value="1">Bench</option>
    <option value="2">Spectator</option>
    <option value="3">Team Member</option>
    <option value="4">Commissioner</option>
</select>
```

2) your `data` array should look like this:

```
data: {
    id: $("#approved_id").val(), //id
    update_group: $("#group_id").val() //group level
}
```

3) error checking is wrong in `user_group_update`, should be:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET group=? WHERE id=?");
if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
 // Check Errors for prepare
    die('User Group update prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
if(!$stmt->bind_param('si', $change_group, $approved_id)) {
// Check errors for binding parameters
    die('User Group update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    die('User Group update execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
```

Comment: Does your success dialog show? I'm not actually seeing where that's defined in your HTML. You might try `alert(data);` in your success function, to see if any of your database errors are being returned (calling `die` with an error message still looks like a success as far as AJAX is concerned)

Comment: Doing `alert(data);` in the success part, I only get a depreciated warning for a variable I have in my php file that I have not done anything with yet... This `$term = mysql_escape_string($term);` .. I have that in another file and it doesn't affect anything php wise. I do get the success message from the AJAX call. I didn't include the div for it in the code I provided. Does it matter that the outputted user info, I am getting the user_id from a db table and trying to find where that matches the id in my 'users' table?

Comment: if you're doing this for an `id` that exists in `user_requests` but is not yet in `users`, then you'll have to do an `INSERT` query in place of `UPDATE`. The way your query is written, the `UPDATE` will "succeed" but have no effect if the `id` is not in the users table. you could also try an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query if you want this form to insert new users AND update existing users

Comment: The id is already in the users table. I am just trying to locate the user_id from the outputted data I had in the form and match that to the id field in the users table. Then `UPDATE` the users table with the new group #.

Comment: I now see that error checking is wrong in `user_group_update`. I updated the answer with fixed code

Comment: Ok, it is saying I have an error in my prepare part of my prepared statement. It was for not having the ``'s around group in it. I changed it and now I am not getting any other errors from there and still no results. I also changed the bind_param to ii, as both are integers.